# background image not showing?

Tags: html, css, sass, 960.gs

ok i have the following html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
        <title>marriage</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="logo">
        <h1><a href="#">marriage logo</a></h1>
    </div> <!-- end logo -->
    <div id="input">    
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
        <input type="submit" value="search .." />
        <p>search for words like: calm, honest ... etc</p>
    </div> <!-- end input -->
    <div id="questions">    
        <h2>Why our website ?</h2>
        <p>because you find your soulmate as easy as possible, just type the word you looking 
            for in your soulmate and press enter to start searching</p>
    </div> <!-- end questions -->
    <div id="side">
        <p>New User or signup if not</p>
    </div>  <!-- end sidebar -->
    <div id="footer">
        Copyrighted &copy; 2012
    </div> <!-- end footer -->
</div> <!-- end of container -->
    </body> 
    </html>
```

and here is the scss file for styling and I'm using 960 grid system for layout

```
@import "compass";
@import "960/grid";

$ninesixty-columns: 12;

html, body {

  @include background-image(linear-gradient(#fcfad0, #FFF));
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }

#container {

@include grid_container;

#logo {
    @include grid(6);
    // @include clearfix;
    h1 {
        background: url(images/logo.jpg) no-repeat;
        width: 480px;
        height: 250px;
        text-indent: -9999px;

        a {

            text-decoration: none;
        }
    }   
}
  }
```

the background image in `<h1>` tag is not showing with the html file, i don't know why .. is there something missing here ?

```
h1 {
        background: url(images/logo.jpg) no-repeat;
        width: 480px;
        height: 250px;

   }
```

Comment: Try to add display:bock;
to h1 in css

Comment: stil not showing .. i tried it before `display: block`

Comment: I know it is stupid, but still, are you sure that your image is in the right place with the right file ending and capitalization?

Comment: i checked it more than one time, i paste complete html and scss here for that .. i can't find the problem ... may be the grid layout .. i don't know

Comment: can we see running code of this?

Comment: @Pankaj Sorry, i don't get what you mean here

Comment: I mean is this site live or something?

Answer (score 1):

I see you use Compass. So you have configured the directory containing the images (ie `images_dir`) in your configuration file.
Instead of to call directly your image, you shoud use the [image-url()](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/#image-url) helper, like this (without specifying the directory images):

```
background: image-url(logo.jpg) no-repeat;
```

Also, if you want to hide the text, you can use the mixin [@hide-text](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/utilities/text/replacement/#mixin-hide-text). And finaly, perhaps that the [@replace-text-with-dimensions](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/utilities/text/replacement/#mixin-replace-text-with-dimensions) mixin is what you want:

```css
h1 {
  @include replace-text-with-dimensions(logo.jpg, 0, 0);
}
```

However, I imagine you want to make the logo clickable. In this case, the code will be:

```
<h1 id="logo"><a href="/">marriage logo</a></h1>
```

and:

```css
#logo {
  a {
    @include replace-text-with-dimensions(logo.jpg, 0, 0);
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: nice i didn't know about this mixin .. thanks for your help :)